# Need help using jQueryUi in Plone

Tags: jquery-ui, plone

I'm new to Plone and jQueryUI, and have not been able to get any jQueryUI working on a Plone page.

I installed Plone 4 (4.1.4 41143) and jQueryUI 1.8.16 (http://plone.org/products/collective.js.jqueryui),

Under Zope Management Interface > portal_javascripts, collective.js.jqueryui.custom.min.js is present and enabled.

To try to implement the example from http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/, I placed in the body text of a Plone page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery({function($) {
        $( "input:submit, a, button", ".demo" ).button();
        $( "a", ".demo" ).click(function() { return false; });
    });
</script>

<DIV class=demo>
<BUTTON type=submit>A button element</BUTTON> <INPUT value="A submit button"  type=submit> <A href="#">An anchor</A>
</DIV><!-- End demo -->
```

but the resulting page does not show the expected result.

I've tried replacing "jQuery" in the code above with "$", "collective.js.jqueryui.custom.min", but nothing has worked yet.

I was able to get some jQueryUI working outside of Plone, but would be interested in knowing how to use it within Plone. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content of your **script** tags is probably being deleted by Plone's HTML filtering. 
You can change that in "Site Setup", "HTML Filtering". (The dialog there is confusing, you have to click two buttons. First remove from 'nasty tags', then 'save' at the bottom of page.)

Be aware though, that there are good security reasons for not allowing users to use **script**, **embed** and other tags. It can lead to all kind of trouble, for instance when they are also allowed in comments, or less experienced users copy/paste dangerous code.

If you're just practicing,  and not putting your site on the big bad Internet, it can be fine, but if you start deploying a real site it is much better to put **script** stuff into page templates of your own file-based add-on product.

Comment: Yes, I think that is likely what was happening. I've just been practicing, and I'll have to learn how to properly include and register, (and invoke,) the javascript when I decide to try to tackle Plone again (it's not as straightforward to just pick up as I'd hoped, so I think I'll just do the jQuery UI for now.) Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax within the `script` tag is incorrect.  Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "input:submit, a, button", ".demo" ).button();
    $( "a", ".demo" ).click(function() { return false; });
})($);​
```

Comment: Thanks TJ. I tried that (removed extra '{' on first line within the script tag, added '($)' in last line within script tag) but unfortunately it's still not working. I must be doing something else wrong as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing any error messages, but instead of a button appearing on the page as expected, I just see the text 'A button element' followed by a link 'An anchor'.

Comment: Are you including the necessary CSS for jQuery UI?

Comment: I wasn't doing so explicitly, but under Zope Management Interface > portal_css, I see an entry for ++resource++jquery-ui-themes/sunburst/jqueryui.css. I don't know whether that's the necessary css. After seeing your question I also tried adding <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/css/base.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> to the Plone page, but still got the same result (no buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may need to allow script tags as described above, but the example still did not work for me until I replaced the word jQuery with the $ sign, at least when using collective.js.jqueryui 1.8.16.9 on Plone 4.2.1.1.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar1" ).progressbar();
        $( "#slider" ).slider();
        $( "input:submit, a, button", ".demo" ).button();
        $( "a", ".demo" ).click(function() { return false; });
     });
 </script>
```

Putting ($) just before the semicolon on the line above  also worked but I saw no difference.

The script worked on a file system page template even when script was included in the "nasty tags" list.  Also, the script can be inserted into the document's head with the following in a page template:

```
<metal:slot fill-slot="javascript_head_slot">
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider();
        $( "#progressbar1" ).progressbar();
        $( "input:submit, a, button", ".demo" ).button();
        $( "a", ".demo" ).click(function() { return false; });
    });
</script>
</metal:slot>
```

(I'd love to hear if there is a more appropriate prefix, but I don't really know javascript.)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar issue trying to get my scripts and jquery UI to work with a plone/zope setup. The solution was to register them in the javascript registry (/portal_javascripts).
The scripts themselves were added to /portal_skins/custom which is also where the homepage I was working on resides. 
Script tags are filtered out from the source as already mentioned above, and the scripts from the registry automatically added instead.
Keep in mind also that order is important in the javascript registry.

Hope this is of some help to other users who come across this question,.